# L'hopital rule for vector sequences?

Tags: limits, vectors, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find the limit
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}{\frac{B.r}{a^*.r}},
$$
where $B$ is a $n\times n$ matrix in $C^{n\times n}$, 
$a$ and $r$ are vector columns in $C^n$. Vector $a^*$ is the conjugate transpose of vector $a$ and $a^*.r$ is the inner product.

Is there any analog of the L'hopital rule for vector sequences?
Or how can I find this limit?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}$? Because for general vectors which norms go to zero this limit is undefined, if only because we can take a vector $r$ orthogonal to $a$ and look at $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow0}\frac{Br}{a^{*}r}$.

Comment: Yes, actually the normtends to $0$, i.e.  $\|r\|\to 0$

Comment: Is there any particular case when $\lim_{\|r\|\to 0}\frac{Br}{a^*r}$ is not undefined?

Comment: As @FlorisClaassens elucidated, the limit fails to exist.

Comment: Let's consider an example. Let $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and let $a=(1,1)$. Then $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B\lambda(1,0)^{*}}{(1,1)\lambda(1,0)^{*}}=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B(1,0)^{*}}{(1,1)(1,0)^{*}}=(2,0)$ and in the same way $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B\lambda(0,1)^{*}}{(1,1)\lambda(0,1)^{*}}=(0,1)$ and $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B\lambda(-1,1)^{*}}{(1,1)\lambda(-1,1)^{*}}=\frac{(-2,1)^{*}}{0}$ is undefined. Note that the fact the scalar $\lambda$ goes to zero has no effect on the outcome.